# I cant run ezdxf,

Tags: python, ezdxf

i just try to use ezdxf, and copied that code from ezdxf website:

```
import ezdxf
doc = ezdxf.new('R12', setup=True)
msp = doc.modelspace()
msp.add_text("A Simple Text").set_pos((2, 3), align='MIDDLE_RIGHT')
msp.add_text("Text Style Example: Liberation Serif",
             dxfattribs={
                 'style': 'LiberationSerif',
                 'height': 0.35}
             ).set_pos((2, 6), align='LEFT')
doc.saveas("simple_text.dxf")
```

and i recieve  that:

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'ezdxf' has no attribute 'new' (most likely due to a circular import)

what may by wrong? installation, path,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you name your file the same thing as the module (in this case, ezdxf.py)? This causes problems with circular imports. Renaming the file should solve it.